# Using Django/Python to CONSUME existing web services

Tags: python, django, web-services, rest

I have an existing REST application serving either JSON or XML. I can use the framework (Play) to render templates directly, but I'm not allowed to (arbitrary homework requirement they just invented), and forced to use a second layer to consume, process and render the REST objects.

I want to use Django/Python if possible. What do you recommend? Something where I'm not parsing JSON directly would be nice.

Is it possible in Django? I would like to do all my templating and views at this level. So something with a good templating language is needed.

Or should I be using something even more lightweight like httpLib/urlLib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your Django app, you can easily use the `urllib` and `json` modules in the Python standard library to pull data from URLs, and then parse them as JSON.

Comment: I would prefer something with proper templating systems built in.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, "in your Django app," I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oooh okay, interesting. So how does one deal with routes at the Django client layer? Lets say my app is providing product details like so: http://localhost/product/${id} . Do I need to hardcode that address into my routes at Django layer?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, the Django app is using HTTP to pull data from another server.  In that case, Django has no information about the other server's URLs.

Comment: Yep that is correct. So it will need to be in the routes config (or whatever it is in Django - never used it).

Comment: No, sorry: the url map in Django is for routing URLs that Django serves.  You will be using Django to pull another server's URL, there's nothing to help you with that.

Comment: Okay cool. But the idea I have is feasible? I'm new to web apps/REST. Can you see a more suitable solution whilst still satisfying the arbitrary (read: stupid) requirements?